# Python replace/delete special characters

Tags: python, replace

```
character = (%.,-();'0123456789-—:`’)
character.replace(" ")
character.delete()
```

I want to delete or replace all the special characters and numbers from my program, I know it can be done in the one string just not sure how to space all the special characters with quotes or anything. Somehow I'm supposed to separate all the special character in the parenthesis just not sure how to break up and keep all the characters stored in the variable.

Comment: What is that code supposed to demonstrate? The first line isn't valid Python, and the next two lines are sort of valid but basically nonsense.

Comment: I want the word character to represent all the special characters in parenthesis, then be able to delete them all or replace with spaces. I know it isn't valid as i cant figure out how to make it work with all the special characters in one line, which is why im asking.

Comment: what do you want to replace them with?

Comment: I want spaces where all the special characters are in my text file.

Comment: what do you consider special characters?

Answer (score 1):

The `translate` method is my preferred way of doing this. Create a mapping between the chars you want mapped and then apply that table to your input string.

```
from string import maketrans

special = r"%.,-();'0123456789-—:`’" 
blanks = " " * len(special)
table = maketrans(special, blanks)
input_string.translate(table)
```

Comment: Or, `blanks=" "*len(special)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good application for `filter`

```
>>> s = 'This is a test! It has #1234 and letters?'
>>> filter(lambda i: i.isalpha(), s)
'ThisisatestIthasandletters'
```

Comment: I would if i could, its for an assignment and needs to use either delete or replace. Really i just need to be able to get character to represent all the special characters in one variable, thats the trouble.

Comment: This code doesn't actually do what it claims (have you run it, in either 2.x or 3.x)? Also, why `lambda i: i.isalpha()` instead of just `str.isalpha`?

Comment: @Samuelfisher: Given that there is no method named `str.delete` or top-level function named `delete`, are you sure this assignment is even for Python?

Comment: @abarnert I'm using 2.7, I literally copy and pasted this from IDLE

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function with an optional fill value, if not set it will just delete/remove the non alpha characters or you can specify a default replace value:

```
def delete_replace(s,fill_char = ""):
    return "".join([x  if x.isalpha() else fill_char for x in s])
```